# Problem redirecting stdout in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, stdout, stderr, buffering, output-redirect

I have the following test Ruby script:

```
require 'tempfile'

tempfile = Tempfile.new 'test'
$stderr.reopen tempfile
$stdout.reopen tempfile

puts 'test stdout'
warn 'test stderr'
`mail -s 'test' my@email.com < #{tempfile.path}`

tempfile.close
tempfile.unlink
$stderr.reopen STDERR
$stdout.reopen STDOUT
```

The email that I get has the contents:

```
test stderr
```

Why is stderr redirecting properly but not stdout?

**Edit:** In response to a comment I added a `$stdout.flush` after the `puts` line and it printed correctly. So I'll restate my question: what was happening and why does the flush fix it?

Comment: What happens when you switch the order of warn and puts?

Comment: Nothing happens when I switch the order of `warn` and `puts`. @mu: I changed the `mail` to `cat` exactly as you wrote and I still don't get the stdout printed. I'm using Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.01 on CentOS Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard output is generally buffered to avoid a system call for every write. So, when you say this:

```
puts 'test stdout'
```

You're actually just stuffing that string into the buffer. Then you say this:

```
`mail -s 'test' my@email.com < #{tempfile.path}`
```

and your `'test stdout'` string is still in the buffer so it isn't in `tempfile` when `mail` sends the file's content to you. Flushing `$stdout` forces everything in the buffer to be written to disk; from the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-flush):

> Flushes any buffered data within ios to the underlying operating system (note that this is Ruby internal buffering only; the OS may buffer the data as well).
>
> ```
> $stdout.print "no newline"
> $stdout.flush
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> no newline
> ```

The standard error is often unbuffered so that error messages (which are supposed to be rare) are visible immediately.

Comment: Interesting, and good point about stderr buffering. I posted a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701103/understanding-ruby-and-os-i-o-buffering) to understand all this better.