# Log file does not get written until server shutdown / does not write with Logger

Tags: logging, sinatra, rack, thin

I am developing a simple web service with Sinatra/Thin on Windows

In my app, I have the following to enable logging to a file:

```
Dir.mkdir('log') unless File.exists?('log')
use Rack::CommonLogger, File.new('log/access.log', 'w')
```

When the server starts up, the file is created. However, nothing is written to the file until I shut down the server.

On the other hand, when I use Logger, like this:

```
logger = Logger.new('log/access.log', 10, 1024000)
use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
```

it does not even write entries to the log file, except for a line that says:

```
# Logfile created on 2013-02-13 11:23:45 +0200 by logger.rb/31641
```

What I need is:

- Log entries to be written immediately
- To be able to Logger for the log rotation feature

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this solution in my sinatra apps (subclassing Sinatra::Base) `before do

    env['rack.logger'] = Logger.new("log/#{App.environment}.log")

    logger.datetime_format = "%Y/%m/%d @ %H:%M:%S "

    logger.level = Logger::INFO if App.production?

  end`

Answer (score 0):

Using a Sinatra Classic Style Application, setting the attribute sync to true of the file for logging, works for me. In production and development:

```
Logger.class_eval { alias :write :'<<' }
flogger = File.open("log/app.log","a")
flogger.sync = true # This is what makes to write always
logger = Logger.new(flogger)
use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
```

Sources:

- Production logging in Sinatra - http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/12/production-logging-sinatra/
- Flush a file in Ruby - [Understanding Ruby and OS I/O buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701103/understanding-ruby-and-os-i-o-buffering)