# how to continuously update a graphics window in ruby using tk

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I'm looking for a way to 'dynamically' update variables (and what's being displayed) in a real time fashion in ruby/tk. Can someone please help modify the code below in a way that when I run the program I'll be able to have the value of blah_text updated by directly assigning values to it from a piece of ruby code?

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'
root = TkRoot.new()
blah_text="yolo"
blah = Tk::Tile::Label.new(root) {text blah_text}.grid
Tk.mainloop()
```

e.g.:

```
magic-procedure 
{
  while (1)
  {
    reads some comma delimited text from a filehandle
    based on the above assigns some value to blah_text_from_file
  }
}

require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'
root = TkRoot.new()
blah_text=blah_text_from_file
blah = Tk::Tile::Label.new(root) {text blah_text}.grid
Tk.mainloop()
```

desired effect :

the tk window continuously updates the text with the values we assign to 'blah_text_from_file' until we close it

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following code produces the effect you desire, and handles Unicode as well.

Until you close the Tk window, it continuously updates the text it displays, by reading the characters you write to a certain file.

Create 'continuous_update.rb' with this code:

```rb
# coding: utf-8

require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

def lambda_clock_tick
  @lambda_clock_tick ||= Kernel.lambda do
    v_clock.value = v_clock + 1
# For later, schedule another clock tick:
    milliseconds = 1000
    Tk.after milliseconds, lambda_clock_tick
  end
end

def lambda_stream_read
  @lambda_stream_read ||= Kernel.lambda do
    entire_contents = nil
    raw = stream.gets entire_contents
    unless raw.nil?
      s = raw.chomp
      v_accumulator.value += s unless s.empty?
    end
# For later, schedule another read:
    milliseconds = 500
    Tk.after milliseconds, lambda_stream_read
  end
end

def main
  l_clock
  l_accumulator # Keep before reading the stream.
  v_clock.value = 1
  lambda_clock_tick.call
  lambda_stream_read.call
  Tk.mainloop
end

def stream
  @stream ||= begin
    filename = File.expand_path 'continuously_update_stream.txt', __dir__
    File.open filename, 'rb:UTF-8:UTF-8'
  end
end

# Tk objects:

def f_content
  $f_content ||= begin
    f = Tk::Tile::Frame.new root
    f.padding '4 4 4 4' # Left, Top, Right, Bottom.
    f.grid sticky: :wnes
  end
end

def l_accumulator
  @l_accumulator ||= begin
    pixels = 200
    l = Tk::Tile::Label.new f_content
    l.textvariable v_accumulator
    l.wraplength pixels
    l.grid
  end
end

def l_clock
  @l_clock ||= begin
    l = Tk::Tile::Label.new f_content
    l.textvariable v_clock
    l.grid sticky: 'w'
  end
end

def root
  $root ||= begin
# Tell Tk which encoding to use:
    Tk::Encoding.encoding = ''.encoding
    TkRoot.new
  end
end

def v_accumulator
  @v_accumulator ||= TkVariable.new ''
end

def v_clock
  @v_clock ||= TkVariable.new ''
end

main
```

Create 'continuous_update_testbed.rb' with this code, in the same directory:

```rb
# coding: utf-8

def console_filehandle
  @console_filehandle ||= begin
    filename = 'con:' # If not on Windows, change this.
    File.open filename, 'r:UTF-8:UTF-8'
  end
end

def console_read
  console_filehandle.readline.chomp
end

def main
  stream # Initialize output file.
  transfer_unicode
  transfer_ascii_from_console
end

def stream
  @stream ||= begin
    filename = File.expand_path 'continuously_update_stream.txt', __dir__
    File.open filename, 'w:UTF-8:UTF-8'
  end
end

def stream_write(s)
  stream.puts s
# See:
#   http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9153
#   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701103/understanding-ruby-and-os-i-o-buffering

  stream.flush
end

def transfer_ascii_from_console
  until 'stop' == (line = console_read)
    stream_write line
  end
end

def transfer_unicode
# Avoid Unicode problems on Windows console keyboard.
# See:
#  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line
#  http://utf8everywhere.org/
#  http://www.honeybadger.io/blog/data-and-end-in-ruby/

  DATA.each_line {|e| stream_write e}
end

main

# The following is "Hello" in Greek:
__END__
γεια σας
```

Here's how to run it:

1. In a `cmd` console, start the testbed program;
2. In another `cmd` console (using the same working directory), start the other program (i.e., the graphical one); and
3. Type some random words into the first console (i.e., the testbed program's console).

Tested using Tk 8.5.12 and Ruby 2.2.5, on Windows 7.