# Tell Ruby Display a Line before going to next etc

Tags: ruby

I understand that you can use the sleep(2) which pause x time before the code displays but I want it to execute and display codes line by line. Eg:

```
x = 1
y = 2

puts x + y #I want this line to show first
sleep(5) #Above line shows but waiting 5 seconds before showing below
puts x + y * 2 #After 5 seconds this line shows
sleep(10) #After 10 seconds etc
puts (x + y) * 2
```

This works great in C programming but not Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a buffering issue. Try adding `$stdout.sync = true` before you use `puts`. [Setting sync to true disables buffering.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-sync)

```
x = 1
y = 2

$stdout.sync = true

puts x + y
sleep(5)
puts x + y * 2
sleep(10)
puts (x + y) * 2
```

Or, you can flush `stdout` manually each time:

```
x = 1
y = 2

puts x + y
$stdout.flush
sleep(5)

puts x + y * 2 
$stdout.flush
sleep(10)

puts (x + y) * 2
$stdout.flush
```

[For more info on Ruby buffering, check out this well-done answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6701442/3124288)