# supervisor empty logfile

Tags: logging, supervisord

I've been messing around supervisor logfile capabilities. The program writes to stdout:

```
ruby sample.rb
>>0.9668821900023237 [tps] 
>>61.91346356232367 [tps] 
>>Heartbeat....
>>58.84168122263758 [tps] 
>>Heartbeat....
```

When I run it from supervisor, I've got log files created, but `stdout_logfile` is always empty. When I mess something in `sample.rb`, so that I have any kind of exception, it is successfully written to `stdout_logfile` due to `redirect_stderr`.

Supervisor configuration file:

```
[program:sample]
priority=50
command=/usr/bin/ruby sample.rb
numprocs=1
directory=/home/myapp/myapp
autorestart=true
autostart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=90
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/sample.out.log
user=myapp
```

Why I see no output on `stdout_logfile`?

Comment: This isn't Python. Freudian slip?

Comment: how comes this isn't python: `easy_install supervisor`

Comment: You can run whatever you want with http://supervisord.org/. It can be python process, ruby process, perl process, bash script.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved by simply calling `flush` on stdout.

```
puts "hello world"
$stdout.flush
```

Related:
[Problem redirecting stdout in Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700726/problem-redirecting-stdout-in-ruby-script)